# Multiprocessing - Manager.list() not true shared memory

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In the python docs, under sharing data between processes...the Manager.list() and Manager.dict() methods look promising.

What is not clear is whether these offer true memory sharing, or if the list/dict is still pickled to the separate processes.  From my performance metrics, I am guessing pickling is still going on.

**Server process**

> A manager object returned by Manager() controls a server process which
>   holds Python objects and allows other processes to manipulate them
>   using proxies. A manager returned by Manager() will support types
>   list, dict, Namespace, Lock, RLock, Semaphore, BoundedSemaphore,
>   Condition, Event, Queue, Value and Array. For example, from
>   multiprocessing import Process, Manager

```
def f(d, l):
    d[1] = '1'
    d['2'] = 2
    d[0.25] = None
    l.reverse()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()

    d = manager.dict()
    l = manager.list(range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(d, l))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print d
    print l
will print
{0.25: None, 1: '1', '2': 2}
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

> Server process managers are more flexible than using shared memory
>   objects because they can be made to support arbitrary object types.
>   Also, a single manager can be shared by processes on different
>   computers over a network. They are, however, slower than using shared
>   memory.

I believe I may to use ctypes, but am not sure if this will accommodate all the types coming back from Oracle.

Comment: It says right there in what you quoted that a process manager is slower.

Comment: But not why, it isn’t obvious whether the performance is due to serialisation.

Comment: It's not using shared memory ("more flexible than using shared memory"), so it must be serialization, especially considering "can be shared by processes on different computers over a network".

Comment: The object being managed is not serialized, but whatever IPC approach that is being used may involve the serialization of some things using pickle. In any case, for a vague answer, youncoyof say "IPC overhead" is the cause

Comment: Not sure what the point is if the IPC more than negates the benefits...

Comment: Just wanted to say that it would be greatly appreciated if anyone could give a comprehensive answer to this question. I've been searching for a few hours now. I've put in quite an amount of time and still have no clue.